# Bash script to match segments in lines of source code

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to learn a new programming language, and it's big. Thousands of new terms to learn. I know programming, but don't know the name used for a certain procedure or constant in this language. But I have a script file that I put together that helps tremendously by searching through a large selection of source files, as long as I get a group of the characters right.

But now I want to use `&&` to match up multiple segments in the same line,  and I want to pass this whole expression to the script file as one argument, so I might pass it this with a read command:

```
moo && cow
```

And it would match this:

```
Moonlight over Moscow
```

But not this:

```
I heard a cow mooing.
```

If I wanted it either way I would pass it this:

```
moo && cow || cow && moo
```

It's tricky, and probably outside what you can normally do with the available syntax.  But then I'm no expert, so I don't really know.

I'm flexible on what gets passed to the script, like single `&s` and `|s`, the use of brackets, and so on.  I just need to understand the rules involved and which utility can do it for me.  Or set of utilities if it comes to that.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is this about parsing command line arguments? Or about parsing (bash) source code? Or are you even trying to create a new language you are trying to parse?

Comment: did you write any code?

Comment: You tagged this [regex]. Why aren't you using them?

Comment: @Mat He is; a regular expression isn't *required* to use metacharacters like `*` and `.`. Ignoring case sensitivity, the regular expression `moo` matches `Moonlight`.

Comment: You want to match "Moonlight over Moscow" but not "I heard a cow mooing." Regex doesn't have the context of the *meaning* of the words...

Comment: I don't think he cares about meaning; I think he just wants to match a line that has `moo`, then `cow`, not `cow` then `moo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check for the two elements in order, simply match anything between them with `.*`:

```
my_str="moonlight over moscow"
if [[ $my_str =~ moo.*cow ]]; then
    echo "match"
fi
```